# Not able to update data in sharepoint list using rest [bad request error]

Tags: jquery, rest

Trying to update data in sharepoint `list` `'Details'` the fields like `name`, `designation` by `listItemID` used below code but getting bad request error.

```
$("#edit").click(function () {

var Ownpass = $("#pass").val();
var Desig = $("#designation").val();


 var listItemID="IBM/1/2011";


      $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Details')/items(" + listItemID + ")",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify
        ({
            __metadata:
            {
                type: "SP.Data.DetailsListItem"
            },


            "Designation": Desig,

            "PassportNumber": pass

        }),
         headers:
        {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Seeking help here: Thanx in advance

Comment: There is no need to use JSON.stringify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have passed ID as integer value instead of ListItemId to update the data and now this code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
var listItemID="IBM/1/2011"
```

you should provide the ID field of the list item.
once check list item type in metadata

you can use this function to get the list item type by passing list title

```
 function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
        return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```